# Python Pandas delete row based on specific condition where list indexing is required

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [[np.nan, np.nan, 0], [np.nan, 1, 1], [1, np.nan, 2], [np.nan, np.nan, 3]]})
print(df)

           A
0  [nan, nan, 0]
1    [nan, 1, 1]
2    [1, nan, 2]
3  [nan, nan, 3]
```

Now I want to remove the rows, where the first two elements of the list are nans so to get this:

```
           A
1    [nan, 1, 1]
2    [1, nan, 2]
```

I tried:

```
df.drop(df[np.isnan(df.A[0]) & np.isnan(df.A[1])].index)
```

But it doesn't work of course. So how to achieve it, while keeping the values a list and not making seperate columns out of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code by adding `str`

```
df = df.drop(df[np.isnan(df.A.str[0]) & np.isnan(df.A.str[1])].index)
Out[20]: 
             A
1  [nan, 1, 1]
2  [1, nan, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the column to intermediate dataframe and then check the counts of values along `axis=1` to identify the rows where the first two values are non-null

```
m = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].tolist()).iloc[:, :2].count(1) != 0
df[m]
```

---

```
             A
1  [nan, 1, 1]
2  [1, nan, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
m = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x[:2] == [np.nan, np.nan])
df[~m]
```

Output:

```
              A
1   [nan, 1, 1]
2   [1, nan, 2]
```